# Spatial data distribution on an area

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, distribution, dbscan

I have a dataset of longitude and latitude points of interest plotted on a graph and I'm trying to infer from that dataset how distributed those points are in reference to a certain area. For instance I want questions like are the points all condensed at the start/end/middle of the specified area? or are the points evenly distributed?

I'm still relatively new to spatial data analysis algorithms and tools, so how would I go about doing so? Is there a certain model or spatial analysis algorithm I can read more about and explore that would help me?

I tried using DBSCAN and clustered the points, but still couldn't figure out how to use that clustered graph to analyze in relation to an area how are the distribution of those clusters are. I'm not sure if DBSCAN can help me achieve that or I should try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two-dimensional kernel density estimation and visualize the result with a heatmap. There's a [nice example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/neighbors/plot_species_kde.html) of this approach by Jake Vanderplas in the scikit-learn documentation.